How to explode arraytype columns in pyspark dataframe
I have a pyspark dataframe as below.
I need to explode the Items and Value1 columns. This is my code at present:
df_ob_exploded = df.withColumn('op_it.objects',
                    F.explode(F.array(*[F.array(F.col('op_it.objects')[i]['Items'][j].Name,
                                F.array(*[F.col('op_it.Objects')[i]['Items'[j]['Items'][k].Name for k in range(9)]).cast('string'),
                                F.array(*[F.from_json(F.col('op_it.objects')[i]['Items'][k].Selected, sc).getItem('Value') for k in range(9)]).cast('string'),
                                F.from_json(F.col('op_it.objects')[i]['Items'][j].Selected,sc).getItem('Value'))for i in range(9) for j in range(9)]))).dropDuplicates()
                                
df_obj_json = df_ob_exploded.select('ID', F.col('op_it.object'[0].alias('Name'), F.col('op_it.objects')[1].alias('Items'),
                                          F.col('op_it.object'[2].alias('Value1'), F.col('op_it.objects')[1].alias('Value'))\
                                          .na.drop(how='all', subset=['Name','Items','Value1','Value'])
                                          

I am unable to explode the Items and Value1 columns.
ID      Name        Items                   Value1      Value
1       Contact     [platform,chat, , ,]    [,,,,,]     null
1       action      [,,,,,,]                [,,,,,]     windows
1       cycle       [,,,,,,]                [,,,,,]     article


I am assuming the arrays are not of the same length so the straightforward explode function won't work here - instead, you can first zip these two columns and then fetch the values from these columns as follows:
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()

data = [
    (1, "Contact", ["platform", "chat"], ["something", "something_else", "something_else_else"], None),
    (1, "action", [None], [None], "windows"),
    (1, "cycle", [None], [None], "article")
]

columns = ["ID", "Name", "Items", "Value1", "Value"]

df_obj_json = spark.createDataFrame(data, columns)

df_zipped = df_obj_json.withColumn("zipped", F.arrays_zip("Items", "Value1"))

df_exploded = df_zipped.select(
    "ID",
    "Name",
    F.explode("zipped").alias("zipped_col"),
    "Value"
)

df_final = df_exploded.select(
    "ID",
    "Name",
    df_exploded.zipped_col["Items"].alias("Item"),
    df_exploded.zipped_col["Value1"].alias("Value1"),
    "Value"
)

df_final.show()

# Output:-
# +---+-------+--------+-------------------+-------+
# | ID|   Name|    Item|             Value1|  Value|
# +---+-------+--------+-------------------+-------+
# |  1|Contact|platform|          something|   NULL|
# |  1|Contact|    chat|     something_else|   NULL|
# |  1|Contact|    NULL|something_else_else|   NULL|
# |  1| action|    NULL|               NULL|windows|
# |  1|  cycle|    NULL|               NULL|article|
# +---+-------+--------+-------------------+-------+


You can try first replacing the empty strings with nulls so it doesn't affect the explode, post that your explode should work as required.
df1 = df.withColumn("Items", F.expr("filter(Items, x -> x != '')")).withColumn("Value1", F.expr("filter(Value1, x -> x != '')"))

df2 = df1.withColumn("Exploded_Items", F.explode_outer("Items")).withColumn("Exploded_Value1", F.explode_outer("Value1"))

Then you alias the columns as needed with a select statement.
+---+-------+--------------+-------------------+-------+
| Id|   Name|Exploded_Items|    Exploded_Value1|  Value|
+---+-------+--------------+-------------------+-------+
|  1|Contact|      platform|          something|   null|
|  1|Contact|      platform|     something_else|   null|
|  1|Contact|      platform|something_else_else|   null|
|  1|Contact|          chat|          something|   null|
|  1|Contact|          chat|     something_else|   null|
|  1|Contact|          chat|something_else_else|   null|
|  1| action|          null|               null|windows|
|  1|  cycle|          null|               null|article|
+---+-------+--------------+-------------------+-------+

